# Apache Web Server Get - File Size

Tags: java, apache, http, data-transfer

I would like to access a local Apache Web Server and its files, let's say, http://foo.com/cats.jpg

I don't want my client to see the image, instead, receive the data, show its file size and the duration of data transfer and flush the file. How can I do it with a Java HTTP code?

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://foo.com/cats.jpg");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

// Get the response but don't show the content, just file size and duration of data transfer
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you use `response.getLastHeader("Content-Length").getValue()`?

Comment: What does this method exactly do? I'm guessing it gets the size of the file, but not the data-transfer time? :)

Comment: When you perform an `html get` operation it returns a response. That response contains headers with important information, along with the content (in this case a .jpg file).  The header can tell you things like the length, the mime-type, etc.  If you need to display the file length, you can get it with the function I mentioned.

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much! Any ideas on how to measure the data-transfer (or connection) time?

Comment: To measure time you can get the current time before doing the `get` operation, then the current time after and subtract. Use `System.currentTimeMillis()` and the difference will tell you how many milliseconds the operation took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform an `html get` operation it returns a response. That response contains headers with important information, along with the content (in this case a .jpg file). The header can tell you things like the length, the mime-type, etc. If you need to display the file length, you can use

```
response.getLastHeader("Content-Length").getValue()
```

To determine how long the data transfer took, just call `System.currentTimeMillis()` before and after the operations you want to time, and subtract them to know how many milliseconds the operations took.  For example:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://foo.com/cats.jpg");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
String size = response.getLastHeader("Content-Length").getValue();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("It took "+(end-start)+" milliseconds and the file is "+
    size+" bytes long");
```